# Gridview selected value not populating Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, sql, gridview, drop-down-menu

In my ASP.NET page I have a gridview and a dropdownlist, I want the dropdownlist to populate with the value from the selected row in my gridview. My dropdownlist is populated with a sql statement:

```
dt = dal.FillDataTable(dbType.SqlServer, "SELECT V_VendorNo + ' | ' + V_VendorName FROM VendorTbl")
    ddlVendorEncum.DataSource = dt
    ddlVendorEncum.DataTextField = dt.Columns.Item(0).ToString
    ddlVendorEncum.DataValueField = dt.Columns.Item(0).ToString
    ddlVendorEncum.DataBind()
```

my gridview templatefields are as such...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vendor">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("v_vendorno").ToString + " | " + Eval("v_vendorname").ToString %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#  Eval("v_vendorno").ToString + " | " + Eval("v_vendorname").ToString %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle Font-Size="X-Small" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have tried this code:

```
ddlVendorEncum.Text = gvEncumbered.SelectedRow.Cells(1).ToString
```

in my selectedIndexChanged event for my gridview but I keep returning an error ("ddlVendorEncum.Items.Add(gvEncumbered.SelectedRow.Cells(1).ToString())
"). Any suggestions?

Comment: "*but I keep returning an error*" - What error?

Comment: 'ddlVendorEncum' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items.
Parameter name: value

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question.  That is important.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use following code this might remove your error:

   ```
           ListItem item = new ListItem();
           item.Text = gvEncumbered.SelectedRow.Cells(1).ToString;
           item.Value = gvEncumbered.SelectedRow.Cells(1).ToString;
           ddlVendorEncum.Items.Add(item);
   ```